# React native dynamic class import breaks the app

Tags: javascript, typescript, react-native, performance, lazy-loading

Trying to build a service provider for multiple app API versions, they differ in routes and data and everything so I'm having a singleton instance with a factory kind of class combined to get versions

Current error:
src/services/SomeApiServiceProvier.ts:
src/services/SomeApiServiceProvier.ts:Invalid call at line 8: import("./v" + version + "/SomeApiService")

```
//Singleton to get the version
export class SomeApiServiceProvier {
    public static async Provider(): Promise<SomseApiServiceInterface>{
        
        const version:string = VersionServiceProvider.Instance.OdooVersion 
        //Current expected and actual value im getting is '10.0' 
        return await import('./v' + version + '/SomeApiService');
        //This line above breaks the app
    }
}
```

Filestructure looks like

```
   SomeApiServiceProvier.ts
        v10.0
           SomeApiService.ts
        v15.0
           SomeApiService.ts
```

So far i tried switching to require and react.lazy but none of those are doing anything

The only thing that works is importing every ServiceProvider and returning them in switchcase but I want to avoid that to save on memory a bit